# Asking about meaning of sentence in English Language Learning

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Can I ask about sentences—which I read from books or whatever—and I didn't get what the sentence means? I will ask on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Probably post this question in English Learning Meta, as this is site specific.

Comment: Each site got its own help center with list of things that are on topic for that site. Read it carefully, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: While [Meta English Language Learners](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com) would seem to be the correct site for this question, this user doesn't have enough reputation on [ell.se] to post on the per-site Meta.

Comment: @Fish still, easy enough to gain meager 4 points and post there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [English Language Learners - What topics can I ask about here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> English Language Learners Stack Exchange is for people who are
> learning or teaching English as a foreign language.
>
> The best questions are those that have specific answers; ELL is not a
> general discussion forum. In general, ask here if you have a question
> which covers:
>
> - Word choice and usage
> - Grammar
> - Dialect differences
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Practical problems you encounter while learning English

That last bullet specifically seems to cover what you're looking for.